# Javascript to clear multiple fields

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out what is probably a simple script but I'm really bad at js.

I have a button that I want to reset fields that are dynamically created.

```
<button type="reset" onclick="clearDiv_<?php echo $mid; ?>();"><?php echo $reset ?></button>
```

I have a script attached to each field

```
function clearDiv_<?php echo $mid; ?>() {
    var t = '<?php echo $id.'_output'; ?>'; 
    var getDiv = document.getElementById( t );
    var emptyDiv = getDiv.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Basically each field is assigned a group ID ($mid). The $id is the individual field ID. Looking at the outputted HTML it looks like it should clear all of the fields but it's only clearing the last field in the group.  How can I make it work and trigger each of the fields the script is attached to?

Comment: This, `function clearDiv_<?php echo $mid; ?>()` is not good...

Comment: you're trying to make function name dynamic..? just use clearDiv()..!

Comment: In case your field id's really are individual field ids, they should be unique and any deletion will affect a single element only. if they are not, `document.getElementById` will still return a single node only while afaik you have no guarantee whatsoever which of the id'd elements that will be. how about issueing the group id as a css class to the appropriate fields and using [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) or jquery with a `. ` selector to delete them ?

Comment: @elclanrs I need `function clearDiv_<?php echo $mid; ?>()` because each group of fields has its own randomly generated id ($mid)

Comment: @collapsar I can give the css a go, I haven't thought of that way yet.